# Why does $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)$ mean choosing $n$ alike objects?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question that involves the number of combinations of $n$ objects out of $3n$ where $n$ are alike of kind $a$, $n$ are alike of kind $b$ and the rest are unlike.

I am aware this apparently means $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)$ for the alike objects and $(1+x)$ for the unlike objects. Buy why is this so?

The only thing I might vaguely interpret is each time for the unlike objects, you have $(1+x)$ to choose from, so you get $(1+x)^n$ overall. But even I don't get why you have $1+x$ options in the first place...

Question: Consider the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^2(1+x)^n$ to find the number of combinations of $n$ objects out of $3n$ where $n$ are alike of kind $a$, $n$ are alike of kind $b$ and the rest are unlike.

Comment: What means $x$ in all your question?

Comment: Ill write the question but im looking more for the understanding explanation

Comment: For context, it is a binomial theorem problem. $(1+x)^n$ can be expanded using the binomial expansion (but I'm not sure if that's useful here)

Comment: @user71207 It is **extremely** useful to (know that it is possible to) expand $(1+x)^n$ with the binomial formula. What do you know about the binomial coefficients in relation to choosing things? That's a large in hint towards how to think about these things.

Comment: binomial coefficients are basically combinatorics. So from the $n$ objects, you can choose $0,1,2,3....n$

Comment: So if you expand $(1+x)^n$, what exactly would the coefficient of $x^k$ tell you about choosing?

Comment: Hmm ok so it says to consider $x^n$. So the coefficient is $n\choose n$ which is equal to $1$! Im not sure how that helps

Comment: The punchline is that what you have here is a "*generating function.*"  When expanding the product of $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)\cdots (1+x)$... we consider "*FOIL*"ing without combining like terms right away.  We will combine them afterwards.  How we "*FOIL*" is by picking exactly one summand from each of the parenthetical phrases in the product.  Such a selection corresponds to a specific way of choosing objects.  Picking a summand from the first $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)$, the exponent of the term chosen corresponds to the number of objects of the "first type" you get

Comment: Similarly, picking a summand from the second $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)$ corresponds to the number of objects of the "second type" you get.  Picking a $1$ vs the $x$ in the first of the $(1+x)$'s corresponds to having not picked or having included the first of the unique objects.  Similarly for the others.  This is merely brute force counting of the possibilities except we organize it in such a way that we can ask a computer for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of combinatorics, we often consider a set of elements, each element having a given size, and we are interested in counting how many elements of each size exist. For a set $A$, let's denote $a_n$ the number of elements of size $n$ in $A$.

It is also usual to count the elements in a product of two sets $A \times B$, and to consider that the size of an element $(a,b) \in A \times B$ is the size of $a$ plus the size of $b$.

Consider the polynomials $P_A = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$ and $P_B = \sum_{n \geq 0} b_n x^n$ (for now, let's suppose that those are finite summations). These are formal polynomials: we are not interested in evaluating them for any value of $x$, so $x$ has no meaning. What is of interest is that $P_A \times P_B = P_{A \times B}$, that is, the coefficients of the product of the polynomials $P_A$ and $P_B$ are the number of pairs of each size! Indeed, one can check that the $n$th coefficient of $P_{A \times B}$ is $\sum_{k \geq 0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$ and that it is the number of pairs of size $n$.

Hence we have that by introducing these polynomials, we get a way to count the product of two sets. This is actually a lot deeper, as several natural operations on sets have a corresponding polynomial operation (disjoint set union is addition for instance), and it also works with infinite sets and formal series, and this is the basis of the very rich theory of generating functions.

Back to your problem, it means that the polynomial $1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n$ describes a set with one element of size 0, one element of size one, and so on. This is actually the case of the set of all possible ways to take up to $n$ items of kind $a$ (because they are identical, it only matters how many we take: there is one solution of each size). Similarly for items of kind $b$, our possible actions are encoded by the same polynomial $1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n$. By multiplying those two polynomials, we get $1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots nx^{n-1} + (n+1)x^n + nx^{n+1} + \ldots + x^{2n}$. This means that, when choosing objects of kind $a$ and $b$, we have one way of taking nothing, 2 ways of taking exactly one element, 3 ways of taking exactly two elements and so on. We not only get how many ways to take $n$ elements, but also how many ways to take $p$ elements for any $p$.

For items of unlike kinds, we must choose individually whether to take them (size 1) or not (size 0), so we get the polynomial $(1 + x)$ for each of those items. Multiplying everything, we get that the coefficients of $(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots x_n)^2(1 + x)^n$ describes the number of ways to take a given number of items of all kinds. In particular the $n$th coefficient is the answer of the question.

Notice that some confusion might arise from the fact that $n$ has several meanings: it is the number of available items of each kind, and the number of items in the solution. By generalizing we can make it clearer: if we call $q_a$, $q_b$, $q_c$ the numbers of available items of kind $a$, kind $b$ and unlike kinds respectively, and keep $n$ for the number of items we pick, then the number of solutions is the $n$th coefficient of $(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{q_a})(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{q_b})(1+x)^{q_c}$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the concept now. Great explanation and read